# D3: Invalid attribute [object Object]

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a JSON list of the following structure:

```
[
    {'uid': 4, 'x': -1.2354657, 'y': -0.992893}
    {'uid': 26, 'x': 0.2783682, 'y': -0.1931}
    ...
    {'uid': 26, 'x': -0.278356, 'y': 0.082983}
]
```

I'm trying to attach `svg:circle` elements to an `svg` at the points specified by the `x` and `y` values in this list. The AJAX request works correctly, but I keep getting `Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cy="[object Object]"`.

Relevant javascript code:

```
var svg = d3.select('#d3')
        .append('svg')
        .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'main')

    ...

var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {return d.x;}))
        .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {return d.y;}))
        .range([height, 0]);
    ...

 svg.selectAll('.bloom')
        .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'bloom')
    .append('circle')
        .attr('class', 'bloom-circle')
        .attr('cx', function (d) {return x(d.x);})
        .attr('cy', function (d) {return y(d.y);})
        .attr('r', 10)
        .style('fill', 'purple')
        .style('stroke', 'white')
        .style('stroke-width', '5px');
```

I literally have no idea what's going on, since `d3.scale.linear` should always return a value in its `range`. Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Are x and y strings or numbers?

Answer (score 0):

The scales return an empty object when the range is not well specified. For example, both the following scales will return `{}` when invoked for any value:

```js
d3.scale.linear.domain([0, 1]).range([0, undefined])
d3.scale.linear.domain([0, 1]).range([0, NaN])
```

Hence, are `height` and `width` well defined at the time of execution?